# Activity indicator in tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a tableview contains xml parsed objects.

I want to implement activity indicator in this tableview ,if the data loading is completed activity indicator stops automatically.

How to do this?.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to make an async call to get your xml data.

Start your activity indicator before making the call then in the delegate method when you receive the data stop the activity indicator the code looks something like this.

```
- (void)getAsyncData
{
    // do something here......
    [indicator startAnimating];
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark NSURLConnection delegate
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [responseData appendData:data];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:responseData];
    xmlParser.delegate = self;
    [xmlParser parse];
    [xmlParser release];
    [indicator stopAnimating];
}
```

Comment: i set the load data in tableview by a button click,there is 4 button and each button click will change the data of tableview,by setting tag property of the tableview

Comment: i want to display activityindictor in table view

Answer (score 0):

after finishing  the parse operation, give a notification to the tableview class , in that method you can reload the tableView and also stop the activity indicator .

Answer (score 0):

I hope, UITableView's "- (void)endUpdates" could be best place to stop your indicator when everything is done with the table.